# How do I buy Torchlight for Linux?

Tags: linux, torchlight

I put off getting the humble indie bundle because I wanted to wait till I could make a large donation and I apparently waited too long.  How do I buy Torchlight for Linux now that the bundle is over?

Comment: PROTIP: you can increase your donation amount after buying the bundle, even after the bundle is no longer on sale.

Comment: @kotekzot He didn't get it in the first place, that was the problem.  Also, Torchlight wasn't one of the "pay more than the average" games.

Comment: There seems to be no way, but I _imagine_ that once you do buy the game and contact support they'll sort you out somehow :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping advice.

Answer (score 2):

It's available via the [Ubuntu Software Centre store](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/torchlight/).

Of course this is not too useful if you don't use Ubuntu, if this is the case you could always contact the guys at Runic Games they may be able to come up with a solution.