# What are the Indie Royale Bonuses?

Tags: indie-royale

When you purchase multiple bundles over at [Indie Royale](http://www.indieroyale.com/), you can unlock multiple downloads as seen in your [collection](http://www.indieroyale.com/collection):

[image: Locked Bonuses]

What are those bonuses?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about purchasing games, not playing them.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot It is not a game recommendation though. It is perfectly answerable and has no multiple answers and does not solicit arguing. I don't see whats wrong with it. Also, previous answers about purchasing games have been answered and left open as long as it is not a game recommendation, which is offtopic. Example: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86794/how-do-i-buy-torchlight-for-linux

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness That's a straight up shopping recommendation.  I'm surprised nobody's VTC'ed it yet.

Comment: @fbueckert How is it a shopping recommendation? I did not ask if it is worth unlocking all those bonuses, I asked what they are.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness It doesn't matter that it's not a game rec.  This is about a website where you buy games.  It is not about any game itself. It's the equivalent of asking what kind of promotions GameStop has.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot It does matter. And it is not temporary

Comment: @OrigamiRobot GameStop promotions are only temporal, no? These bonuses are present ever since the collection option is available and I doubt they'll go away

Comment: @Zommuter It doesn't matter if they're temporary of permanent.  The problem is the question is about a business and not a game.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Then we must also prohibit all questions about Steam, UPlay or Origin and delete the tags for those.

Comment: No, those are platforms which allow you to play games.  If there was a question asking which bonuses you get when you buy something on Steam, I'd VTC that too.

Comment: Huh.  I was sure we allowed these types of questions, but I can't find a single one that's still open.  Now, if this were about pre-order bonuses in a game, I'd say it's worth re-opening, but it's just about products you get by buying other products.  They are games, yes, but the question is not about the games, it's about the bonuses.  I believe therein lies the critical problem.

Comment: The critical problem lies within some of the users here.... Indie Royale, Indie Gala and Humble Bundle are sites that are frequented by Gamers more often than they like and therefore, such a question is likely to attract people to our site. It is already ranked 7 on google when you search for it. Therefore, it is a good fit. I won't repeat my other points now, as I have written them multiple times. But the question covers none of the prohibited topics from the help center. The allowed topics are outdated anyway.

Comment: The _only thing_ you can use the information in the answer for is for shopping related things.  If that's not asking for shopping advice, I don't know what it.

Comment: You are totally wrong. It is what the unlockable bonuses are. This is not a shopping advice at all. A shopping advise would be to ask if a game is worth the purchase. This question asks for what the unlockable bonuses on a gaming related site are. I don't why you cannot grasp the difference of such questions. It is the same as someone asking how to trade games on Steam. That has nothing to do with playing games either, but we allow it. I think you guys closed it because it was me who asked it. Again.

Comment: I don't even know who you are.  Please give me an example of how you can use this information for anything non-shopping related.

Comment: Can we move this discussion to meta or chat?

Comment: @Schism Won't change the outcome. Those guys work together and rule this site, there is no "community decision" or anything close to that. So no point in harassing meta about it. Just leave it be.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I agree that this question should be reopened (I fail to see the difference between this and a question about pre-order rewards), but at the same time, I think you're being a tad disingenuous, and that a more positive tone and attitude would elicit more positive response. And no, I really don't think everybody is out to get you.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness People argue about stuff like this all the time and decisions are often reversed or overruled. This is pretty much exactly how policy gets set.

Comment: Okay, open a meta question if you guys want to talk about this further.  (I will happily defend this question on meta if someone else doesn't beat me to it...)  Comments unrelated to asking for clarification about the question may be purged...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: indieroyale unlocked]

- [Chiptopia Album](http://8bitweapon.bandcamp.com/album/chiptopia-the-best-of-8-bit-weapon-computeher)
- [Super Space Rubbish + OST](http://www.indieroyale.com/games/preview/super-space-rubbish)
- [Fireball](http://www.indieroyale.com/games/preview/fireball)
- [Corril Slayer](http://www.indieroyale.com/games/preview/corril-slayer)
- [Pushcat](http://www.indieroyale.com/games/preview/pushcat)

Comment: A good answer to an off-topic question.

Comment: Pushcat!  That game is great!