# If the average price of a Humble Indie Bundle goes up, will I get the games that are added later?

Tags: humble-bundle

I bought Humble Indie Bundle 9, beating the average, and got all the games.

The page states that there are more games to come:

[image: More games coming]

But the average is now above what I paid earlier. Will I get the additional games, or will I have to pay more, to reach the future average price?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a flag in the system that gets turned on at time of purchase.  Not 100% on that, though.

Comment: I'll be anxious to see your answer in a few days when you did/didn't get the newly added games!

Comment: It looks like they changed the behaviour now, you used to get all the bonus games no matter how much you paid.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a website sells games.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Steam questions are on topic, I don't see why we would then exclude Humble Bundle questions

Comment: @MadScientist Because steam is required to _play_ games.  It's more than just a marketplace.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Well, there is a Humble Bundle application for Android, which assists in playing games... So if we allow Steam questions that have absolutely nothing to do with games themselves, why not allow this?

Comment: @all See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122407/what-are-the-indie-royale-bonuses). Open a meta question if you want to discuss more.

Comment: Same goes for Linux or other platform related questions. They are not directly linked to being a game :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, if you pay above the current average, or increase your payment to above the current average at any point, you will receive any additional games added to the 'beat the average' tier.

If you look at the text on the image you linked:

[image]

> Pay more than the average of x to unlock them when they arrive!

This means you'll get any new games when they are added.

---

Extra Source: I've done it.

Comment: To avoid all possible confusion: if the moment you pay, you paid over the average, you get flagged as "paid over the average". Even if later on, the average goes up, and goes above what you paid, new "above average only" games still become available to you.

Answer (score 8):

**[Edit]** The bonus games are now out, and as everyone assumed, you **do** get the bonus games now if you previously beat the average.

However, HiB9 is notable for being the first Humble Bundle that does **not** give the bonus games to people who bought in the first week but did *not* beat the average!

Comment: This is really interesting. But some proof would be nice...

Comment: -1 The image shows otherwise. A pattern in the past is not proof something will repeat in the future.

Comment: Actually he's right, I've done this too, but the image does seem to state otherwise.  Maybe they've changed it?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy: The pattern from every past bundle **is** proof of what's likely to happen again.  Of course, it's not *definitive* - they could obviously change how it works.  But considering it's always worked the same way, and that the creators of Humble Bundle have always [made a blog post](http://blog.humblebundle.com/post/14549340777/1-min-price-for-getting-steam-keys) before making any major changes, it seems unlikely that will happen.

Comment: +1. I've purchased several bundles as gifts for friends that were not BTA, but they got the extra games later anyway.

Comment: The strange thing to me is that in previos humble bundles there were no icon that would say you have to pay more than average to get the other games that will come out later. That in it self is a change so it could be that the business model has changet as well, other wise what the point of adding the icon.

Comment: The wording under the icon is suspiciously specific, as if they wanted to specify that this time you'll have to beat the average anyway even if you made the purchase in the first week.

Comment: Agree with @AGameBot and Kappei

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in the Humble Indie Bundle 9, where the bonus games are only available to people who had already beaten the average. Once you do beat the average once, however, you don't have to beat it again when the bonus games come out.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; OP already knows that the later-added games are based on beating the average, what he wants to know is what happens if the average price goes up over what he paid before the new games are added.

Comment: This answer, as it is, is confusing and poorly worded. Please consider improving it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you originally paid more than the average than you are fine.

Think of it this way, at the moment you paid your above average amount, that more games image amount said Pay more than X (And at this time that X is what you were aiming for) so you fulfilled the requirement, you don't need to keep fulfilling the requirement after you already did so to begin with.